# LDA: Good rule-of-thumb for minimum number of words per document?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, lda

I am creating a semantic space using LDA or Hierarchical LDA. I'm working form a collection of ~45000 texts, some of which are very long (e.g., Moby Dick). Others are relatively short.

My plan is to break the texts into smaller chunks and consider each of these chunks as a "document" for purposes of generating the semantic space.

What is a good rule-of-thumb for how long to make each document? My understanding is that LDA [much moreso than LSI] prefers to work with longer texts, so rather than just breaking the texts into paragraphs, I am currently planning on breaking them into paragraphs and adjoining paragraphs until I get 200 terms (after text pre-processing, removing stop-words, etc.)

Is 200 a good number for this?

This will yield something like 3,800,000 million documents for training.

Does the answer differ between LDA and HDP-LDA?